# Margin is seemingly not being animated when a class is removed

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have a header bar that I am hoping to animate (using CSS transitions) when the user scrolls down the page. I have the animation I want sorted, but the margin doesn't seem to animate back to 0 when the class is removed (notice the obvious jump when the header is animated to the smaller version.)

Can anybody see a reason for this? As far as I can tell the margin should transition back to 0 without any issue.

**HTML**

```
<div id="top-background">
  <div class="sky-blue">

  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
  margin: 0;
}

#top-background{
    margin-top: 0;
    transition: 2s height ease-in-out, 2s transform ease-in-out, 2s margin-top ease-in-out;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #1a82c5;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
}

body.expanded-header #top-background{
    height: 500px;
    margin-top: -19.27083333333%;
    transform-origin: 100% 100%;
    transform: skewY(-10.9deg);
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/d1y0r3q1/1/)

(Click the blue to toggle class)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the `transform-origin` onto the `#top-background` element seems to fix this.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d1y0r3q1/2/)

Comment: You are so right. The transform origin is only applied when the body has the class, so not when it is getting smaller. Thanks for highlighting this for me!

Comment: No problem, glad it helped. @George